# How to securely print private key and protect against attacks on printer itself?

Tags: key-management, printers

As we know, there are various possible attacks on printers, so it is not very secure to print high-security things like private keys for bitcoin/gpg/etc. on a random printer.

What I'm mostly concerned about is hacked firmware and side-channel attacks, but maybe I'm looking at this wrong.

I don't worry about the network because I can connect the printer directly to the computer that is not connected to any network.

Comment: Do you mean using a public printer?

Comment: @M'vy No. I wan't to but secure printer, but I don't know which hardware is secure against side-channel attacks. For example see this https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity10/acoustic-side-channel-attacks-printers. Note: I didn't watch this video as I'm familiar with this subject.

Comment: Why you want to print the key?

Comment: @Crypt32 for backup e.g. against hardware failure. It's common to create cold offline wallets for Bitcoin, for example.

Comment: Have you considered hand writing?

Comment: Re: handwriting. If it's long binary data, you may want to write down the beginning of the sha256 hash (16 hex characters would likely be enough) so you'll be able to verify you typed it in correctly, and then you can write down the base32-encoding of the data so that case doesn't matter. You could use scrypt on the data first to encrypt the data with a password.

Comment: Yes, I considered hand writing, but this is not feasable solution for me as I don't have time, plus I want to do it multiple times (e.g. various cryptocurrency wallets). It seems weird to me that no one created security centered printer these days, especially after all published research and leaked information about printer attacks.

Comment: Many printers have a huge storage and store almost everything they print. There is often no way around this. Older ink-jet printers are less likely to do this than modern laser-jet printers, however. Perhaps you could use a digital typewriter, and destroy the ink cartridge (which contains the typing history in the form of removed ink) afterwards. A similar dot matrix printer may also be a good idea, as there is less risk of the letters being imprinted, however slight, on the typewriter paper bail.

Comment: From the comments, it appears that you are looking for a product that will do what you want, not a process or an approach.